# Numerical Analysis- Finding two closest machine numbers in single precision.

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, machine-precision

There is a question that is similar to this that was asked already, but the answer did not really make too much sense to me. Let's say I have a number 4096.000244 and I want to find the two closest machine numbers to it in IEEE single precision, so the closest machine number above and the closest one below. How would I go about doing this? I converted the number into binary, but I am not too sure how to continue on from here.

Link to similar one I mentioned:
 [Find the closest numbers in double precision](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117776/find-the-closest-numbers-in-double-precision)